# Declare global variable in action script?

Tags: actionscript-2

I want to create a variable(possible global variable) in one action script file and want to use the same variable across all other action script files in the project. How to create such a variable and how to use the same variable across all .as files??

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to define a [static](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/oop2/AS2OOPClassStructure4.htm) variable in a Class (either create a new Class or use one of your existing classes):

```
// in MyConfig.as
class MyConfig {

    static var myVariable:String = "Hi";

}

// You can access / set the value from any class using MyConfig.myVariable
trace(MyConfig.myVariable); // prints Hi

MyConfig.myVariable = "Hello";
trace(MyConfig.myVariable); // prints Hello
```

Comment: But it says attribute used outside the class.

Comment: Did you define a new class or did you add the static variable to one of your existing classes? Try adding the "public" keyword before the "static" keyword (it should not be required because if I remember correctly members are public by default in AS2).

Answer (score 0):

Create one public class (lets assume GlobalVariables.as)
No need to add its instance.
Now declare all the variables that you want to use across multiple classes as STATIC.
(you can also declare and create instances of classes in that class to avoid multiple instances of classes)
Also you can add common methods to this class

So whenever you want to access that variable declared in GlobalVariables class
you need to access using reference e.g GlobalVariables.variableName

sample code:

```
package classes{    
    public class GlobalVariables{
        public static var strURL:String;
        public static function setExternalLinks(){          
            strURL = "http://demourl.asmx/";
        }
     }
}
```